# Did Jesus ever say that Heaven is the end?

Tags: heaven, gospels

> Did Jesus ever say that Heaven is the end?

...And what I mean is: Did Jesus ever leave open the possibility of reincarnation on Earth, another planet, or elsewhere?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it doesn't specify the perspective from which it is seeking an answer.

Comment: @FMS: The perspective? I added a `gospels` tag because I'm looking for a Biblical reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The gospels do not specifically address the question, but the book of Hebrews does.  It is appointed for men to **die once**--not many times.  After that is the judgment--not one of many judgments--**the** judgment.

> And inasmuch as **it is appointed for men to die once** and after this comes judgment, so Christ also, having been offered once to bear the sins of many, will appear a second time for salvation without reference to sin, to those who eagerly await Him.